# Opening a file from within a function

Tags: c, function, file-io

I'm working on a piece of homework and I want to send a FILE * into a function as an argument since I have to open 3 files in an identical manner with some "flavor text". I got it to work fine like this:

```
enum {IN, STAT, REPRINT} FNAMES;
#define FNAME_MAX 256

int main(void)
{
  FILE *in, *stat, *reprint;
  char fnames[3][FNAME_MAX]; // store actual file names input by user
  char format[11];           // format identifier used in scanf for file names


  in = stat = reprint = NULL; // TODO: Check necessity

  buildFormat(format); // this translates FNAME_MAX into the string "%256s[^\n]"

  // TODO: Find out why this cannot be put into a function!
  // open the input file
  while (in == NULL)
  {
    // get input file name
    getFileName(format, fnames[IN]); // simply prompts for a file name/path

    // open the input file for reading
    in = fopen(fnames[IN], "r");

    // make sure it opened
    if (in == NULL)
      printf("%s did not open, please check spelling/path.\n\n", fnames[IN]);
    else
      printf("%s was opened successfully.\n\n", fnames[IN]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What will not work is this:

```
void openFile(FILE *in, char *format, char *fname, char *openFor)
{
  // TODO: Find out why this cannot be put into a function!
  // open the input file
  while (in == NULL)
  {
    // get input file name
    getFileName(format, fname); // simply prompts for a file name/path

    // open the input file for reading
    in = fopen(fname, openFor); 

    // make sure it opened
    if (in == NULL)
      printf("%s did not open, please check spelling/path.\n\n", fname);
    else
      printf("%s was opened successfully.\n\n", fname);
  }
}
```

if I put file reading operations in the function it works fine, but if I go back to main and try to use the file pointer I sent in it doesn't work.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: pointer to a pointer, do you speak it? and why are you *returning a value* from this function you declare as returning void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C functions do not modify their arguments, so if you really want the function to modify the FILE * you can add a level of [indirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection), as in openFile(FILE **in... and call it with &in. Ugly, yes. The more common practice is as the other answers says, returning a pointer...

A humorous quote found while making sure my fallible memory circuits were using the right words, "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" --David Wheeler

Comment: Thanks again. I figured that since I was sending in a pointer that it would work as if it were a char *, int *, etc with the FILE type, but obviously not. 

I got it to work fine by returning the FILE *

Answer (score 2):

You want `openFile` to return a `FILE *`.  Get rid of `FILE *in` from your input arguments.  Declare `FILE *in` as a local variable and return its value when done.

You probably also want to declare `fname` locally, unless you need to use it after `openFile` returns.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do need to retain the file name for later use, but thanks for the tip.